# Include non-electron folder as part of the NSIS installation

Tags: electron, nsis

I've been trying to add additional functionality to the electron installer, where I copy some files that are packaged inside the installer, but I receive a non-descriptive error when I try to compile my electron project to create the installer i.e. I get:

```
* writing effective config
* packaging
* building
x [object Object]
```

Here is what my script looks like:

```
!macro customInstall
  Rename "$APPDATA\myfolder\img" "$APPDATA\myfolder\img-old"
  SetOutPath "$APPDATA\myfolder"
  File /nonfatal /a /r "additional_files\*"
  CreateShortcut "$SMSTARTUP\mylink.lnk" "$INSTDIR\mylink.exe"
!macroend
```

Basically everything works except the file copy part. When I remove that part the project builds and compiles into an installer with no problems.

I've also tried to use `CopyFiles` instead of `SetOutPath` and `File` and it works as expected when I place the `additional_files` folder into the same folder as the installation (`dist` folder), but I want the folder to be packaged inside the installer. However, I cannot get the `additional_files` to be packaged with the installation.

I believe it's a location issue, that is, that the `NSIS` script cannot locate the `additional_files/` folder. I've tried modifying the `package.json` file by adding to the `files` section the `additional_files/` folder and placing it in the root of the project.

I've even tried placing it in the `build` folder where my `installer.nsh` script resides, but with no luck.

Comment: What happens if you remove the nonfatal? Does the electron builder hide the makensis error message?

Comment: Are you using `electron-builder`?

Comment: @tpikachu yes I am

Comment: @Anders It shouldn't hide the error messages from makensis, but it seems the version of electron-builder I am using does and only displays `[object Object]`. The version of `electron-builder` I am using is `21.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

`File` looks for files relative to the directory where the .nsi is by default. `/NOCD` can be used to prevent that but I'm not sure if electron uses that switch.

`!cd` can be used inside a script to change the directory but I'm not sure if that is going to help you much in this case unless you are willing to use a absolute path and in that case you could just use the absolute path with the `File` instruction instead.

If you only know where your .nsh file is I suppose you could try `File /r "${__FILEDIR__}\additional_files\*"`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `electron-builder` you have two options inside the settings

`extraResources` this will copy files into the `$INST_DIR/resources` folder in your app (this is where the `app.asar` file is too), and you can access via `process.resourcesPath`, ex:

```
extraResources: [
    { from: './dist/ThirdPartyNotices.txt', to: 'ThirdPartyNotices.txt' },
]
```

`extraFiles` this would do the same but place the files into the `$INST_DIR` root folder of your installation ex:

```
extraFiles: [
    { from: './distrib/mytool.exe', to: 'mytool.exe' },
],
```

to get the root folder you can use something like `remote.app.getAppPath().replace('resources\\app.asar', '').replace('resources/app.asar', '');`

all info on: https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#overridable-per-platform-options